# `aws apigateway put-integration`: "Lambda function ARN must be in same account"

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I am trying to follow this [otherwise excellent post](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https-example-configure-event-source.html) to deploy a Java-based AWS lambda app. I'm scripting it out as instructed in that post. I receive the following error when calling `aws apigateway put-integration`:

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the PutIntegration operation: Lambda function ARN must be in same account
```

I'm trying to script the creation of an API gateway to a lambda function.  Here's the [full deploy.sh script](https://github.com/joshlong/putting-the-fun-in-spring-cloud-function/blob/master/demo/deploy.sh). I  have on my local machine the requisite `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID` environment variables.

I don't  know enough to understand what that error is telling me. AFAIK, the access secret and id and account ID are all from the same IAM user.

Thank you very much in advance for any ideas/help.

Comment: Check if `arn:aws:lambda:${REGION}:${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:function:${FUNCTION_NAME}` indeed exists in the associated `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID`

Comment: thank you for the very prompt reply. How do I confirm that? I created the function in the lines right before this one, so I thought it would be under the same account..

Comment: you can list Lambda function using `aws lambda list-functions` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/list-functions.html or in aws console `Services >Compute >Lambda`

Comment: Hi @hjpotter92 and Chacko Mathew your comments both solved it for me. Thank you so much. I was several hours down that rabbit hole and your replies spaked some investigations that resulted in an answer. thank you. hjpotter92 i would accept your comment, since it was first, as the answer if I could. Do you want to re-submit is an answer? Than you!

Comment: @JoshLong You can answer your own question including more details about what exactly you were doing wrong :)