# “Lambda function ARN must be in same account” while `aws apigateway put-integration`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, command-line-interface, aws-sdk

I am trying to follow this otherwise excellent post to deploy a Java-based AWS lambda app. I'm scripting it out as instructed in that post. I receive the following error when calling aws apigateway put-integration:

> An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the
>   PutIntegration operation: Lambda function ARN must be in same account

I'm trying to script the creation of an API gateway to a lambda function. Here's the full deploy.sh script. I have on my local machine the requisite AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and AWS_ACCOUNT_ID environment variables.

I don't know enough to understand what that error is telling me. AFAIK, the access secret and id and account ID are all from the same IAM user.

### My AWS CLI Script

```
aws apigateway put-integration --region ap-south-1 --rest-api-id xxttj6inea --resource-id bgncc0 --http-method GET --type AWS --integration-http-method POST --uri arn:aws:apigateway:ap-south-1:lambda:path/2019-09-20/functions/arn:arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:***********:function:Hello/invocations
```

Thank you very much in advance for any ideas/help.

Comment: Why you duplicated josh long question here   , are you not able to write your own questio ?                                                        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109998/aws-apigateway-put-integration-lambda-function-arn-must-be-in-same-account

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a copy/paste of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109998/aws-apigateway-put-integration-lambda-function-arn-must-be-in-same-account)

Answer (score 1):

This error can happen because of two reasons:

1. Your AWS CLI settings are incorrect. I'll implore you to check the AWS CLI configuration file, and run test API calls for the same to verify if everything is set up appropriately.
2. Your Lambda function belongs in one account, and your REST API in API GW belongs in another account.